# What constitutes a loot hoard. When can I give my party a horde treasure?

Tags: dnd-5e, treasure

I am new to 5e and a new DM.

My party ended our previous 3.5 campaign on lvl 3 and we started a 5e campaign on level 4.

In the DM manual and on most of the sites that generate random loot there is a reference to loot hoard.

I understand this can be from multiple creatures hoarding loot over a long time or a dragon or so on, but how do I make an encounter that justifies a loot hoard.

I might be missing the point but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Check out the [tour] as it gives a basic outline of how we work. Most notably is that we're not a site designed to give advice but to answer specific questions and solve specific problems. Can you please further explain exactly what you looking for here, what problem you're having and how it isn't covered in the DMG? Most of this seems to be explained in the DMG so I'm not sure exactly which parts you're not understanding or having trouble with.

Comment: Related? http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87077/what-is-a-treasure-hoard-and-when-is-it-apropriate-to-award-one