# What treasure could be in a vampire's tomb for a 1st-level party?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, treasure

I created a D&D 5e module. There is an ancient vampire's tomb as the module endpoint. The tomb was opened by a random human who dug through a cave wall near a tomb the day before the players arrived. The ancient vampire that lived there made him his spawn and flew away, because there is a lot of water in the cave (to save a 1st-level party of 4 PCs from it).

The player characters could meet the wet damaged Vampire Spawn as the boss. I am not sure if they could fight it or not, because they just ignored all plot hooks about water.

If they do fight it, there should be some nice loot here, but what kind of loot could be in the ancient vampire's tomb for a 1st-level party? I realized that I just didn't think about this when I created the plot. I am even not sure that the vampire should have any loot inside his tomb except his stone coffin.

Maybe there are some common rules for such things? Or some usual approach? I really have troubles with explaining to players why there are any treasures in the vampire's tomb. On the other hand, I can't just leave them without any reward.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Unfortunately, this sort of idea-generation question isn't suited to the StackExchange Q&A format, as every answer is potentially equally valid; there's no way to determine a single "best" answer. Such questions might be better suited to a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).

Comment: You seem to be asking two different questions, one about using a Vampire Spawn against a first level party and one about awarding treasures. You might want to refine those and/or split them between separate questions.

Comment: Do you have access to the Dungeon Master's Guide?

Comment: @PJRZ Yes, I have GM guide

Comment: @Someone_Evil no, there is only question about treasures

Comment: @Ohar Then you may want to clarify that in the question, and per V2Blasts comment are you asking how to choose appropriate treasure for a first level party, or asking for specific ideas (which would be [off topic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here?

Comment: Related: [What is a Treasure Hoard and when is it apropriate to award one?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87077/what-is-a-treasure-hoard-and-when-is-it-apropriate-to-award-one?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Someone_Evil The question is more about if it would be suitable to have a treasure in an ancient tomb at all? And, if it is, what kind of treasure would be suitable for such place?

Comment: That is entirely up to your own setting, @Ohar. It's not something that is objectively "true" for D&D, which is why your question was closed as 'opinion based'. The "best" answer would be entirely subjective to personal tastes.

Comment: @Theik Maybe there are some common rules for such things? Or some usual approach? I really have troubles with explaining to players why there are any treasures in the vampire's tomb and also I can't just leave them without any reward.

Comment: The DM handbook describes how to generate level appropriate rewards, but leaves the fluff of it up to you, because what you find suitable for a vampire is entirely different from some other DM. Stackexchange doesn't handle idea generation very well which is why we only allow questions with an objectively true answer. You could try making a topic at a D&D reddit or a D&D forum, which are formats better suited for idea generation.

Comment: @Theik Thank you. I think I'll go to Reddit with it.

Comment: @Theik: Technically we don't only allow questions with "objectively true" answers; per [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), we can handle some kinds of subjective questions, as long as it's possible to determine a "best" answer supported by evidence or experience. Unfortunately, this isn't one of those.